# How to make constant db connection for each user with flask/sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make "constant" (until logout) connection with DB for each user session.

On every api call user should be connected with his connection not one of available in pool

Im using Docker with tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.7

Config:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session


engine = create_engine('mysql://....')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)
DBSession = scoped_session(Session)
```

Route example:

```
sess = DBSession()
call= text("CALL call(:mode, :session,'');").params(mode=mode, session=session['session'])
res= sess.execute(call).fetchall()
return ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5101, ssl_context=context, debug=False, threaded=True)
```

After build im using show processlist to check results. Right now there is only one connection for all.

Maybe i misunderstood something..

Edit: I need to keep connection in order to access temp tables.

Comment: I am not sure if it’s right, you can use flask’s `session` object to store db session for the user.

Comment: How? Can you provide some example? I thought flask session can store variables